How can I train a decision tree or simple ML model with spike detections
I am looking for some advice for my problem. I have a spike detection algorithm that detections outliers in a signal. I have annotations in my dataset that tells me if I am in 3 events, basal, event A and event.
I made an heuristic decision model based on the time between the spikes and the amplitude of the spikes but I want to explore using another model and training with my annotations.
I have very basic ML knowledge. I have trained some models but in other problems I have sequential data in windows ( I was getting features in a windowed appraoch) however, in this case, I am not using windows but the spikes are detected when they occur.
How would you recommend addressing this problem? Is it possible to train a ML model that from several characteristics such as inter-spike time, spike amplitudes, or any other feature?
